# Abstract component Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, abstract-class

Is it a good practice to create an abstract component with Angular 2? Like this:

```
export abstract class TabComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {...}
```

Comment: I think it's generally really bad practice. A component should be in harmony and be a wrapper with its view template. Any variable or method in my view should be directly in my component. Passing anything from a service or abstract class to a template is one step away from just using globals.
If the components share logic, use a service, if they share parts, create a new shared component with inputs and outputs. What else do they share? I hope you're not just trying to save on typing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using a component like this. There is no problem.

But benmarking and reading give me the following attention point : inheritence in Javascript will be manage in an array of prototypes, so rather use composition.

Comment: Here's an example : https://plnkr.co/edit/9ZytO6gGZYaiAd4MrCA1?p=preview look at the array of prototypes in console